# Problems with holding date_format in php

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

Hi I am making a website for events and I wanted to display the date from the database..

if i jus retrive the date as it is the query is working..

Now if I want my date to be printed as Sunday 12th January 2013, I run the query given below and it works jus fine in mysql but wen i run it thro my webpage its not happening...

d_o_e is my date of event column name.

```
$sqldate="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d_o_e, '%W %D %M %Y')FROM events WHERE event_id=$event_id;";
$result=mysqli_query($connect_db,$sqldate);
$rowdate=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$dateformat=$rowdate["d_o_e"];
```

How should I go abt it? 
How to hold the value returned by the query??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using alias

```
$sqldate="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d_o_e, '%W %D %M %Y' ) as `d_o_e` FROM events WHERE event_id=$event_id;";
```

whne you ran your query the column name you are getting is `DATE_FORMAT(d_o_e, '%W %D %M %Y' )`  and not `d_o_e` . So use  alias to make it simpler.

If you enable the error reporting you must be getting `undefined index error` for your code .

Hope you got what I meant .

Comment: oh oh thanks thanks @Let's Code it worked... Im so happy ....  Thank You... So was the value being returned this (DATE_FORMAT(d_o_e, '%W %D %M %Y' )) instead of actually The date??

Comment: Glad to help you. Value is fine but column name was not .Try googling it. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

DATE_FORMAT is a mysql function and you should assign variable name for result, such as:

`$sqldate="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d_o_e, '%W %D %M %Y') as formatted_date FROM events WHERE event_id=$event_id;";`

and then use like `$dateformat=$rowdate["formatted_date"];`

Comment: +1  This will likely resolve the issue. In terms of SQL, we refer to the "AS  formatted_date" as an 'alias' for the column. What that is doing is assigning an alias to that column in the resultset.